# SQL Help for combining two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to combine these two SQL queries into one. Any idea on how do I do it?

```
Select A, B, C 
from table1 
where condition1


select D 
from table2 
where table1.B=table2.E
```

(table2 has the mapping of column B of table1)

I just want to fetch A,B,C,D in a single select query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are going to be writing any SQL you need to understand what a JOIN is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `join`:

```
select A, B, C, D
from table1 
left join table2
on table1.B = table2.E 
where condition1
```

Answer (score 2):

INNER JOIN (read up on joins here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT A, B, C, D
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.B = t2.E
WHERE condition1
```